# imageview inside a listview ontouch for change image don't work

Tags: android, listview, touch

i have a custom row for listview. With a TexView and ImageView.
I would like that clicking on the image it changes color like a button.
I have tried to use setOnTouchListener in my adapter, but it does not work well.

```
public class ListaAreeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Aree> {


public ListaAreeAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List aree) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, aree);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_area, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.nome = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_area_nome);
        viewHolder.cancella = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_area_cancella); 
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Aree area = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.nome.setText(area.getNome());
    viewHolder.cancella.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.i("toccolista", "tocco = "+String.valueOf(motionEvent));
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ((ImageView)view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_yellow_down);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                ((ImageView)view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_yellow);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                ((ImageView)view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_yellow);
                break;
            }
            return false;               
        }
    });



    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView nome;
    public ImageView cancella;
}}
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a selector and set it as background to imageview

Comment: if I use a selector even when click on TextView (row) the background of imageview change color...

Comment: apply selector to only imageview

Comment: thanks fo idea, very good, but i would like different event if i click row of listview and imageview in row...so if there was a programmatically method i prefer...thanks

Comment: you still use OnItemClickListener for list items and in getview you can use OnClicklistener for iamgeview

Comment: it don't function, when i click on the row, all selectors, even those not touch change color, example if i touch textview, both the textview and imageview change color, other the row basic...

Answer (score 0):

Use selector for `ImageView`

Say: `image_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_yellow_down" />    
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_yellow_down" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_yellow" />
</selector>
```

And use it like

```
<ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
     android:background="@drawable/image_selector" />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: if I use a selector even when click on TextView (row) the background of imageview change color...
then I have to click on above image to match a different event by clicking on the TextView ...

Answer (score 0):

i solved with:

http://www.anddev.it/index.php?topic=1087.0

I hope it will be of help to someone...